# Randomly select subset of all combination in Python

Tags: python, random, combinations, python-itertools

I can construct a list of all combinations of n-length binary values `itertools.list(product([0, 1], repeat=n))` when n is small.

```
1000
0100
0110
1001
 .
 .
 .
```

How can I randomly select a subset of the list above without first constructing a massive combination list when n is big?

Let say I want to randomly pick 1 million combinations without replacement when n = 30 (2^30 combinations in total)

I looked at an extended function from itertools http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes

```
def random_product(*args, **kwds):
    "Random selection from itertools.product(*args, **kwds)"
    pools = map(tuple, args) * kwds.get('repeat', 1)
    return tuple(random.choice(pool) for pool in pools)
```

but it only returns once at a time. Should I do a loop of this function until I get 1 million of unique combinations? or there is a better way. Thanks!

Comment: looks interesting. But can you create a simple [mcve] to show what you're getting and what you want? (with smaller values than 1 million of course)

Comment: Pretty sure it is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13919481/generating-a-10000-bit-random-sequence) but can you confirm that it works for you first?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could think about the problem in another way. Essentially you just want 1 million random values between `0` and `2^30`.

```
import random

num_selections = 1000000
range = 2 ** 30

def make_set(n, max):
  result = set()
  while(len(result) < n):
    rand = bin(random.randrange(max)) # converting to binary
    result.add(rand)
  return result

s = make_set(num_selections, range)
```

This runs in about 2 seconds on my machine. This method would not be efficient if `n` is roughly equal to `max`. But `1000000 / (2^30) ~= 0.000931`, so it works fine.

Edit:

@user2285236's solution is more concise:

```
import random
random_group = random.sample(range(2**30), 10**6)
random_group = [bin(x) for x in random_group] # convert all to binary
```

Comment: Or just `random.sample(range(2**30), 10**6)`

Comment: @user2285236 that generates all the values. OP doesn't want that. The alternative is to use a `set` for unicity (random generator is pretty good so there's not a lot of repeats), like this good answer

Comment: I would have changed to `bin` _after_ we're sure that `rand` isn't in result, so you're converting to binary string only if it's necessary

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre What do you mean all values? It generates 10^6 distinct integers between 0 and 2^30 (which then can be converted to binary as mysteryDate did).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Good point about the binary conversion. I don't know off the top of my head, but I would be very surprised if it was computationally expensive. I just realized the conditional isn't necessary though because `set` ensures unique values on its own

Comment: @user2285236 I think in order for sample to work it first needs to allocate in memory all possible values, hence the issue.

Comment: Not really. random.sample's implementation is very similar to yours and it can sample from a range without generating all the values in that range. Try `random.sample(range(2**62), 2)` for example, you will get a result instantaneously. `list(range(2**62))` on the other hand raises a memory error on my 16gb computer. random.sample docs mentions this detail: "To choose a sample from a range of integers, use a range() object as an argument. This is especially fast and space efficient for sampling from a large population: sample(range(10000000), k=60)."

Comment: yes, you have to make sure that you're running python 3, but it's even better (and is probably using the same mechanism to store the indexes, using range object like if it was a list but without generating the values). Make that an answer.

Comment: @user2285236 You've convinced me. I like your answer more.

Comment: @user2285236 @mysteryDate `random.sample` then convert it to `bin` does exactly what I'd want to do thank you!